# Why isn't Perl giving error for try/catch when leaving out Try::Tiny

Tags: perl

I was moving some code around and left out the 'use Try::Tiny' on a piece of code. When I run it, perl runs both blocks of code so the catch fires which fortunately lets me see the error. It appears the try and catch are being used as labels. I thought labels needed a colon after them? Why didn't perl catch this ?

here's the code:

```
#!/grid/common/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

foo();

sub foo {

    try {
    print("hi\n");
    }
    catch {
    die "FATAL: this went wrong, <$@>";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the [indirect object syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax) biting you.

```
try {
  print("hi\n");
}
catch {
  die "FATAL: this went wrong, <$@>";
}
```

Gets interpreted as:

```
(do { print("hi\n") })->try(
   (do { die("FATAL: this went wrong, <$@>") })->catch
)
```

Yeah, really.

There's a module called [indirect](https://metacpan.org/release/indirect) that can give you a compile-time warning when an indirect method call is detected.

Comment: wow. that's really ugly. I thought I was going crazy when I saw this. wish there was a warning for this. Adding another use just incase this happens seems kind of silly. Thanks for the explanation.